# org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder - java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Only certain classes can access this method

Tags: java, static, classloader, logback, slf4j

In our application (App1), we use logback slf4j and another team's jar (App2). App2 also uses logback. Our version of logback is newer than theirs. We've added exclusions on their jar in our maven.

**Note:** added a `-verbose:class` and ensured that only our logback jar is being classloaded

Deploying App1 on weblogic, we are getting the following exception at runtime:

```
Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
Reported exception:
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Only certain classes can access this method.
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder.init(ContextSelectorStaticBinder.java:59)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:92)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at eg.App2.somepkg.App2sServletContextListener.<clinit>(App2sServletContextListener.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.getNewInstance(WebComponentContributor.java:252)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.createInstance(WebComponentContributor.java:297)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.createInstance(WebAppServletContext.java:4209)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.createInstance(WebAppServletContext.java:4197)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.registerEventListener(EventsManager.java:538)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.registerEventListeners(EventsManager.java:139)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.registerEventListeners(EventsManager.java:97)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1908)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3063)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1830)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:875)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:237)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:232)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:82)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:753)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:263)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:67)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:265)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:481)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:53)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:202)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:52)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments$2.doItem(ConfiguredDeployments.java:592)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.parallel.BucketInvoker.invoke(BucketInvoker.java:138)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionAppsParallel(ConfiguredDeployments.java:600)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:259)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:155)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:221)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:130)
    at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1262)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:332)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:374)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:234)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:643)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext does not implement the requested interface org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:237)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:232)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext does not implement the requested interface org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at eg.App2.somepkg.App2sServletContextListener.<clinit>(App2sServletContextListener.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Looking at

```
ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder.init(LoggerContext, Object)
```

and

```
org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init()
```

I suspect this variable to be the culprit

```
org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.KEY
```

What is the use of this `private static variable` ?

What is the need for this piece of code in a singleton class?

```
if (this.key == null) {
    this.key = key;
} else if (this.key != key) {
    throw new IllegalAccessException("Only certain classes can access this method.");
}
```

**EDIT/Workaround:**
I had only the following in the weblogic-application.xml's `<prefer-application-resources>` and `<prefer-application-packages>`

```
<resource-name>org.slf4j.*</resource-name>
```

Adding this also solved the issue - no more IllegalAccessException, but still not clear why/how!?

```
<resource-name>ch.qos.*</resource-name>
```